# como definir DataGrid desde código en WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Alguien me puede dar un tip de como hacer lo siguiente, he  estado buscando y no he podido dar con ello!

Quiero hacerlo mediante código c#

```
<Grid>
   <DataGrid Name="Encabezado" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
       <DataGrid.RowDetailTemplate >
             <DataTempleate>
                 <DataGrid Name = "Detalle>
                 </DataGrid>
             </DataTempleate>
       </DataGrid.RowDetailTemplate >    
   </DataGrid>
<Grid>
```

Como sería crear lo mismo pero desde c#.

Quiero hace esto porque tengo un `TreeView` definido asi en WPF..

```
<TreeView Name="tree">
</TreeView>
```

y con código estoy creando los nodos del treeview, pero dependiendo del nodo 
estoy creando dentro de cada nodo un `DataGrid`, pero solo he podido lograr que
me muestre los encabezados, quisiera que al darle un click a un registro del datagrid me mostrada el detalle pero dentro del mismo datagrid.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, Gracias!

Comment: Creo que te va a dar dolores de cabeza, pero [mira esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5592399/579895)